# Unable to display api results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, get

please am i doing anything wrong?
the response from this api shows on the console but its not displaying on the h3.i dont really know what i am doing wrong.

```
 export default function Overview(){
      const [title, setTitle] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchbalance();
    },[]);
      const fetchbalance = () => {
        axios
            .get('https://finall-app.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/62b208fab5e09b628baa2429/accounts/totalBalance')
            .then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          setTitle(res.data)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
      return (
        <div className='OverviewBox'>
          
          <div className='first-box'>
         <Card border="light" className="shadow-sm">
                <div className="category-text">
    
                  <h5>Balance</h5>
                  <h3 className="mb-1">{title.data}</h3>
                </div>
                  
                <div className="small mt-2">
                  <span>
                    +%
                    <BiUpArrowAlt className="up-arrow"/>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="lastly">
                <p>Compared to($21340 last year)</p>
                </div>
                
          </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked this url:

```
https://finall-app.herokuapp.com/api/v1/users/62b208fab5e09b628baa2429/accounts/totalBalance
```

And it returns:

```
{"totalBalance":400000}
```

So probably:

```
<h3 className="mb-1">{title.totalBalance}</h3>
```

But I'm not sure why some balance should be a title

Comment: HI, thanks
nevermind the name tho...I suck at naming